# Document in two languages

Tags: formatting, languages, text

I would like to write a document in two languages (French and Esperanto) with these constraints :

- on the same page, I would like on one side (the left one) my text written in French and on the other side (the right one) its translation in Esperanto (see page1.png)[image]. I tried with a \twocolumn command but the text from one column often overlay the other one.
- the text from one column is always on the same column. I mean, with the \twocolumn command, when I reach a new page, the text from the right column continues on the left column of the new page (of course), I would like it continues on the right column (same behaviour for the other text). In page2.png, you can see the normal behaviour of two columns, the text continues on the other side.[image] In my mind, I would like this text continue on the next page, left column again.
- tricky bonus: I would like to add images, so once for both languages, that means centered in the page, without considering the two columns.
- if possible, the texts for both languages are in separated TEX files, loaded in each column (with \input for instance).

Thanks to @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I loaded the reledpar package. But I have a strange behaviour: the text start well but the other text begins in the same column and then on the other one (see page3.png)[image]

```
\documentclass[french,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\colorthree}
\newcommand\colorthree[1]{\colorthreeX#1\color{ForestGreen}\hrulefill}
\newcommand\colorthreeX[3]{{\color{ForestGreen}#1#2#3}}

\newcommand{\ite}[1]{\textit{\color{ForestGreen}#1}}

\title{
    {\textsc{\huge{Zen Agile Practices}} 
     
    \large{Version Française / Esperanta versio}}
    
    \vspace{1cm}
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{images/Flag_of_France_(1794–1815,_1830–1974).svg.png} 
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{images/Flag_of_Esperanto.svg.png}}


\author{Me}
\date{Mars / Marso 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
%\tableofcontents

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
        \pstart
            \input{FR_avant_propos}
        \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}

    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
        \pstart
            \input{EO_avant_propos}
        \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside} 
\end{pairs}
\Columns
\end{document}
```

An example of the input files:

```
\section*{Avant-propos}
De nombreux cadres Agile proposent leur interprétation du \ite{Manifeste pour le développement Agile de logiciels} de 2001, chacun apportant sa propre vision et ses règles pour atteindre ses objectifs. Nous basant sur les pratiques réellement implémentées depuis plusieurs décennies ainsi que sur les retours de nombre de ces cadres, nous proposons un modèle simplifié et cohérent pour progresser au mieux dans la culture Agile. 

ZAP met à disposition des comportements, des idées cohérentes entre elles, un état d’esprit permettant de suivre n’importe quel modèle répondant aux principes, qu’il soit petit ou à l’échelle.

ZAP propose un cadre minimal et minimaliste pour conduire n'importe quel type de projet en suivant les principes ancestraux de la philosophie Zen : \ite{vivre dans le présent, ici et maintenant}.
```

Do you think it's possible? Any idea or advice?
Thank you very much and have a nice day.
Benoît.

---

Problem solved, here is what I'm a able now to do:
[image]
I use the Parallel package for this:

```
\usepackage{parallel}
...
\begin{Parallel}{0.45\textwidth}{0.45\textwidth}
    \ParallelLText{\input{Espéranto/EO_avant_propos}}
    \ParallelRText{\input{Français/FR_avant_propos}}
\end{Parallel}
```

Thank you everyone for your help.
Benoît.

Comment: Have a look if the reledpar package might be what you are looking for

Comment: Yes it is possible, but please can you post an image of a sample of what you trying to achieve? How pany pages do you expect the document to be?

Comment: @yannisl I added some example.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I will check it right now, thank you.

Comment: @BenoîtDarroux, in general you should also copy the content of the 4 files used as `\input`, at least in a rudimentary form. Else it's difficult to test. Thank you.

Comment: @MS-SPO Done. That just plain text in these kind of files.

Comment: @BenoîtDarroux, thank you for the French. what's about Esperanto? // Ok, the images are missing too ... I suggest to run through theses steps and adjust your code, so these are no longer issues: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 . Thank you

Comment: Maybe you only need to know that `\newpage` is also to switch columns?   That is,  in normal two columns  mode,  `F \newpage E \newpage F \newpage E`   do not make 4 pages but 2 pages with  two left "F" columns, and two right "E"  columns. Otherwise, take a look  to [CTAN topic about this](https://ctan.org/topic/parallel) where there are also other packages for this kind of texts.

Comment: Thank you @Fran, I finally use the Parallel package, it works better now. 
I will update and close this post.
Thank you everyone for your help.